# Compiler compile which one first Object or String?

Tags: java

Which class compile first, `Object` or `String`?

`Object` needed the same class in return type of `toString` and `String` extends the `Object` class.

Comment: It does not matter. Java does not use a single pass compiler.

Comment: @BevynQ The point is really that it isn't a 'single file' compiler. Merely using multiple passes wouldn't be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to implement a compiler. However the basic way is to parse the source and build a symbol table. Then use that symbol table to convert the source into the destination code.

A single pass compiler can only use symbols it has already encountered. `Pascal` is an example of a language designed to use a single pass compiler. It would be difficult if not impossible to implement `java` using a single pass compiler.

Most languages however use `multi pass` compilers, as the advantages of single pass compilers are no longer significant, in this case it becomes trivial to use symbols that have not been defined yet as the assumption is they will be encountered later in the parse phase.

So as long as the entire `java.lang` package is compiled at the same time the cross dependencies can be resolved. If on the other hand you were trying to compile each class individually the parser will complain because it would get to the end of the parsing pass and have unresolved symbols.

Answer (score 5):

Neither. Just like any other pair, or cycle, of mutually dependent classes, they are compiled simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

In order to compile any other classes, *javac* must first have access to a version of the `Object` class, since other classes are derived from that class.  If a version of the class is not present in the *javac* classpath, *javac* will (if it can find the source) compile `Object` "on the fly" before compiling any other classes.

This same rule holds for any other superclass of a class being compiled.  Eg, if you compile `SubclassX` which is a subclass of `SuperclassX`, and SuperclassX.class is not in the *javac* classpath, *javac* will require that Superclass.java be available to compile.

Comment: String & Object class both are interdependent how it will compile.

Comment: It holds for *all* interdependencies: `implements,` for example, and use of a class as a member, or as a method parameter or result, or as a generic bound. It isn't confined to the superclass relationship. In this case, if you compiled `Object` first, it would have to compile `String` because of `Object.toString().` Your answer actually suggests that `Object` is compiled first, which isn't the case.

Comment: @nicks - *javac* does a bit of sleight-of-hand.  To compile a subclass it only needs certain parts of the final .class file, so it compiles up to where it has those parts, then goes off to compile the other class.  I've never looked inside, but I presume it has a sort of queue scheme to get all the dependencies processed in the correct order.